# How to change the colors of payment method tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a test E-commerce site on WordPress/WooCommerce.

https://siera.mcdir.ru/checkout/

Excuse me for the Russian language but this is not important now.

I am trying to change the payment method button color depending on the method currently chosen.

But unfortunately I am not able to catch the appropriate JavaScript event.

There are no any event listening on the switchers like 
`<label for="payment_method_***">Cash on delivery</a>`.

So the "Woocommerce" software operates on the overall body click event.

The trouble is that. I try to obtain the 'display' property of one out of two payment methods description blocks. But this property is changing by animation software. So I am obtaining the old property value which is certainly incorrect.

Please see the picture.

```
  var paym_click_counter=0;
  var ch_bttn=function (method){

  paym_click_counter++;
  console.log('vodka_check_paym_bttn №',paym_click_counter,'method=',method);
 var pm_01='payment_method_cod';
 var pm_02='payment_method_bacs';
 var paym_elms_arr=$('div.'+pm_01);
var display_01=paym_elms_arr.css('display');
 //    var display_bacs=$('div.payment_method_bacs').first().css('display');
if('block'==display_01){
   console.log('display_01 - block!',display_01,'display_01',display_01);
    $('label[for='+pm_01+']').css('opacity','0.9');
    $('label[for='+pm_02+']').css('opacity','0.5');
} else {
    console.log('display_01 - none!',display_01,'display_01',display_01);
    $('label[for='+pm_01+']').css('opacity','0.5');
    $('label[for='+pm_02+']').css('opacity','0.9');

}


   };
   ch_bttn(1);

   $('body').bind( "click", function(e) {
     console.log( 'e bind',e );
    ch_bttn(3);
  });

   .................
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    document.addEventListener("click", ch_bttn(1));
   });
```

Comment: Your link goes to a 403 error. If I remember correctly, the payment methods are radio buttons and so you could also listen for the `change()` event.

Comment: Excuse me! There was "deny from all" statement. Please try once more.

Comment: This is the screenshot
http://prntscr.com/ptncbq

Comment: Obviously I am greatly confused! Take a look on the screenshot http://prntscr.com/ptqqbs . I see inappropriate alteration of checked/anchecked attribute there!

Comment: Thank you for the useful hint! Everythins is wording properly! This helps: $('#'+pm_bacs).change(function(){ var bacs_checked=$(this).attr('checked')....